# Что можно подставлять в качестве значения параметра X при использовании этого класса в программе?

Tags: java

Предположим, у нас есть параметризованный класс

```
public class Example<X> {
    ...
}
```

Что можно подставлять в качестве значения параметра X при использовании этого класса в программе?

1. имя любого интерфейса (например, CharSequence)
2. символ "?" или более сложное выражение с ключевыми словами extends и
   super
3. значение X можно не указывать, т.е. использовать класс Example как
   обычный     непараметризованный
4. имя любого класса (например, Object)
5. имя любого примитивного типа (например, int)
6. ссылку на метод (например, Object::toString)
7. имя любого перечисления (например, DayOfWeek)
8. значение примитивного типа (например, 42)

Объясните пожалуйста, почему не подходят ответы 1, 2, 3, 4 ?

Comment: Это что тест для юзеров стака или вопрос?

Comment: @GenCloud там вопрос в конце)

Comment: Да, это вопрос с которым мне нужна помощь ,потому что я не понимаю ,почему варианты ответов под номерами  1 2 3 4 неверны

Comment: у вас неверная информация, правильные ответы  именно те, что перечисленны ниже, плюс еще вариант под номером 7

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Аргументы типов в Java определены в спецификации в [п.п. 4.5.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5.1).

В качестве аргумента по спецификации можно поставить ссылочный тип (`ReferenceType` в Java любой непримитивный тип) либо маску (`WildCard`, т.е. выражение `? extends/super T`).

Вот пример допустимого использования `Example`:

```
Example<CharSequence> a = new Example<CharSequence>();
Example<?> b = new Example<Object>();
Example<? extends List> c = new Example<List>();
Example d = new Example();
Example<Object> e = new Example<Object>();
```